# (Java) Static generic methods versus generic class static methods

Tags: java, generics

I've read posts about why you can't have a (Edit -- generic) (which use that type parameter from the generic class) static method in a generic class, but why can you then use static generic methods in non generic classes? I don't see the why the second is allowed, but I kinda understand why the first isn't.

Comment: I edited the question, sry bout that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *why you can't have a (Edit -- generic) (which use that type parameter from the generic class) static method in a generic class*

The reason for this is simple: The type parameter is not associated with the *class* but with *instances* of the class.

I.e., you can't do

```
class Test<T> {
    public static void sayHello(T t) {    // T for which instance?!
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

> *why can you then use static generic methods in non generic classes?*

Why wouldn't you? A generic method takes the type parameter, so it doesn't matter if it's static or not, or if the class it's in is generic or not etc.

This for instance compiles fine:

```
class Test {
    public static <T> void sayHello(T t) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + t);
    }
}
```

And you'd call the method like this:

```
Test.<String>sayHello("some argument");
     ^^^^^^^^
     type parameter provided at the method-call: no instance required.
```